# How can i deploy to a function app in Azure without warnings?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli

I use the following to deploy to a function app in Azure :

```
 az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g $resourceGroupName -n $functionName --src 
 $sourceZipPath
```

The functions are not deployed, but i get the following warnings

```
[error]WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
```

It also gives the error:

```
ERROR: ResourceNotFound - The Resource 
'Microsoft.Web/sites/testfunctionappa88bc' under resource group
```

'testrg'

But testfunctionappa88bc is the storage account so why is it giving this error ?

How can i not get these errors ?

Do i need to publish using the Publish profile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-source-config-zip-examples):

Firstly I have executed below command:

```
az login
```

[image]

Then I have executed below commands:

```
$sourceZipPath="C:\Users\\source\repos\FunctionApp999.zip"
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "v-bojja-tree" -n "rithfi"  --src $sourceZipPath --build-remote true
```

[image]

Firstly you need to login to azure account using `az login` Then use above commands you will get successfully deploy as I have got.You will not warnings when you give correct inputs.

The errors which you got are saying that the function app which you have mentioned is not found under the resource group, please give the resource group name where the function app is created.

[image]

> But testfunctionappa88bc is the storage account so why is it giving this error

Here you shouldn't give the storage account name you should give function app name. `rithfi` is the function app name in my command.(you need to create a function app in Portal and only then you can publish it using above command).

**Update:**

Without build remote:

```
$sourceZipPath="C:\Users\source\repos\FunctionApp999.zip"
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "v-rbree" -n "rithfi"  --src $sourceZipPath
```

[image]

**Update2:**

Go to Function app  click on `App service Editor` then click on Open editor you will find your function app.

[image]

[image]

You can also run them as below:

[image]

Comment: But i will mark it as helpful in trying to solve the issue

Comment: well an update, from visual studio deployment , i can see the functions now. I tried msbuild and couldnt.

Comment: is there a deployment file that Visual Studio produces that i can use ?

Comment: something else to note , not sure if its an issue . The function app was created as .net 4.8, but the project in VS is .net 7.0 , is there some sort of mismatch in the way i deploy ? Since VS deployed ok ?

Comment: No there will not be their any deployment file and glad that you can see functions now, No their is no issue you can change to .net 6 or 7 in portal istelf.